# value of an integral between 0 and 1 by using the binomial theorem

Tags: integration, binomial-coefficients

How can one find the value of the integtral [image]

with an integration by parts I found the value m!*n!/(m+n+1)!
but still I cannot see how to use the binomial theorem here.
Greetings and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok, how about if we write;

\begin{eqnarray}
(4-x)^{n} &=& (-1)^{n}(x-4)^{n} \\
          &=& \sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{n}x^{i}(-4)^{n-i}
\end{eqnarray}
I decided to pull out a factor of $(-1)^{n}$ to keep in line with most literature resources when considering the binomial expansion of (say) $(x+a)^{n}$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Does this lead you onto anything useful?